# Run Delphi program on OS X from MSBuild

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Most of our automated builds runs on Windows, but OS X is needed for generating the help file index and code signing. Is there a way to run a Delphi program on OS X from MSBuild? It's very simple to do this from within the IDE, but I'd like to automate it.

Comment: You might need to describe your hardware setup. Real OSX machine, or a VM? Windows on a Mac in a VM?

Comment: @David: All real machines, no VMs

Answer (score 3):

For automation with multi-platform build steps, I highly recommend a CI tool like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) / [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

You can assign a build task to a specific agent which is running on OSX. Components of the build will be created on the correct operating system.

If your target is full build automation, CI tools are worth a look or two.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Our builds are laughably simple though, so learning a new tool could take more time than the tool can save us.

Comment: Not to quibble, but this doesn't answer the question asked (not downvoting). The question was "Is there a way to run a Delphi program on OS X from MSBuild?", and this doesn't address that question at all.